# SQL Server 2008 Select performance on 10 Mil records table - slow?

Tags: sql-server, performance, select

I have a table with 10 million records and need to load all in memory (cache application).

Table structure is like:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable] (
    [Id]        [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RefId1]    [int] NOT NULL,
    [RefId2]    [int] NOT NULL,
    [RefId3]    [int] NULL,
    [Credits]   [money] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_Table] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([RefId1],[RefId2],[RefId3])
)
```

Table size is about: 364080 KB (data) - 341648 KB (index)

To load this amount of data with a simple select takes about 2 minutes.

Select used:

```
SELECT  Id, RefId1, Credits, RefId3
FROM    TestTable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Is this a normal speed performance for SQL Server?
How can I speed up this query?

The query was tested from the caching application and SSMS, the result was practically the same.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Std, on a 16 core server with 32 GB Ram and SSD Disk RAID, with no other applications or connections to the SQL server.

From the performance counters I can see that there is no queue/disk/cpu usage because the database is completely in memory. When executing the query the only visible information is a slow network traffic between the SQL and SSMS of about 6 MB/s.

All tests were done on the local machine.

Any suggestions on how to speed up this or where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not SQL server problem, it is more about transferring huge amount of data from DB to your local Windows swap file/memory. Why do you need all the table, SQL server will figure out what pages should remain in cache during normal scenarios.

Comment: We are caching all data in our service to provide better responsiveness to our transaction system. Cached tables rarely changes. The service works great for now, but we are looking into speeding up the restart process.